# Lifting of product of a Banach algebra

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a non unital Banach algebra. The product induces a bounded linear map $T:A \otimes_{\gamma} A\to A$ where $\otimes_\gamma$ denotes the Banach projective tensor product.

A lifting of $T$ is a bounded linear map $L:A\to A \otimes_{\gamma} A$ such that $TL=Id_{A}$.

> Do you know a charaterization or examples of algebras which admits a such lifting?

Any reference on this problem or explicit examples is welcome.

UPDATE: I added non unital.

Comment: You certainly want to impose further restrictions on $L$ and $A$. For instance, if $A$ has a unit $1$, then you can take $L(a) = 1 \otimes a$, so the unital case isn't very interesting. A necessary condition of course is that $T$ is onto (if $A$ has a bounded approximate unit then this follows automatically from Cohen-Hewitt). In particular, if $A$ is factorable and is isomorphic as a Banach space to $\ell^{1}(S)$ then you have such a section as well. You might want to google for 'virtual diagonal' and 'amenability' and browse in the books of Runde and Helemskii for more interesting results.

Comment: (I would call it a section of T.) Any Banach algebra with identity would be an example, for example $L^\infty$ or spaces of bounded continuous functions with respect to sup norm. Or, any Banach algebra obtained by adjoining a unit to another Banach algebra. 

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
@Theo Buehler:
Where is written the result: "if $A$ is factorable and is isomorphic as a Banach space to $\ell_1(S)$ then there exist a section??

Comment: I don't know where it's written but it's rather trivial: factorable is equivalent to surjectivity of the multiplication (and hence of $T$). A bounded linear map on $\ell^{1}(S)$ is determined by the images of the standard basis (Dirac's $\delta_{s}$). Abusing notation, we may choose a preimage under $T$ of each $\delta_{s}$ inside a bounded set of $A \otimes_{\gamma} A$ (you can take $\|T\|+\varepsilon$ as a bound), this determines a linear map $L: A \to  A \otimes_{\gamma} A$ such that $TL(\delta_{s}) = \delta_{s}$.

Comment: Big Bill, without some further motivation this question seems a bit too wide-ranging to me. Mere curiosity will not get us far I fear. (I also think that you should call this a splitting problem rather than a lifting problem.) There are two aspects to the problem, it seems: first one has to find non-unital algebras for which $A\hat{\otimes}_\gamma A \to A$ is surjective, and then ask if there is a linear section as Theo has said. Note that it is not necessary for the first question that A be factorable: try $\ell^1$ with pointwise multiplication. (Try Googling "biprojective".)

Comment: (To clarify: In some cases "factorable" means that you can factorize each element as a product of two other elements; this is in general stronger than requiring the linearized product map T to bbe surjective.)

Comment: @Big Bill: Last comment for now: I think it would help us, and you, if you gave in your question some examples of algebras where you already know this works. This will give us some idea of how much you have already worked on the problem, which kinds of example you are interested in, and so forth.

Comment: @Yemon: I think you're a bit severe. From the tags, it seems BigBill tries to understand some *very* basic stuff you can find in Helemskiis books. But, you know, there is a huge difference between knowing you *can* find the answer to a specific question in these books and actually finding it, at least for me... (Maybe I'm just saying I'd  very much welcome vol 0 of the book of which you'd love to see vol 2). Finally, I apologize for my somewhat careless wording of my last comment. I didn't mean to imply that factorable is equivalent to surjectivity of $T$, but as it is written this is unclear.